# How to get orgId programmatically for web-to-case form?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, community

I'm running a community site and wonder, if there is a way to get `orgId` for the web-to-case form programmatically via the LWC JS controller. If not I have to work on that value each time I deploy the form from one to another Org (eg. Sandbox > Production). Thank you for your help!

Comment: Not sure, if I'd recommend this...: Configure a label, populate it on Sandboxes and prod with resp. orgIds (never deploy your label) and then do: `import orgId from '@salesforce/label/c.orgId'` ?!

Comment: @FelixvanHove - what a great idea! Like it alot. Thank you very much - made my day!

Answer (score 1):

You can grab it from the controller with

```
String orgId = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();
```

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, that's possible. But as a label is easier I would rather go for that solution instead of building a controller just for that...